# How to update UI thread from a separate thread without blocking it?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I know that this type of question has several answers on the web, but I think I am unable to understand some parts.
I have made an Android app which will read a file specified by the user and display the contents inside a `TextView`. For handling large files, I separated the file reading task onto a separate thread. Here is the code in `MainActivity.java` file:

```java
package com.mapsup.fileviewer;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText path;
    TextView contents;
    String file_path;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        path = findViewById(R.id.path);
        contents = findViewById(R.id.contents);
    }

    private void checkPermission() {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission was granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission was denied\nApplication cannot work\nPlease enable permission in settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void display(View view) {
        checkPermission();
        file_path=path.getText().toString();
        contents.setText("");
        Thread t=new Thread(new Reader());
        t.start();
    }

    class Reader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                File f=new File(file_path);
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String line;
                while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                    final String finalLine = line;
                    contents.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            contents.append(finalLine +"\n");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                contents.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        contents.setText(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, somehow the UI thread still gets blocked while reading large files. What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way of communicating with the UI thread from a different thread?

Comment: Use handler to communicate between the ui and the background thread.

Comment: That's the thing I am having a problem with.

Comment: I think you must fill an StringBuilder with your file's lines and after `while` statement set contents text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `runOnUiThread()` method which makes sure your code block executes on `Main` thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                      // write your code to run on Main Thread

                       }
                    });
```

You can call this method from some worker thread, for ex:

```
    class Reader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                File f=new File(file_path);
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String line;
                while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                    final String finalLine = line;
                    contents.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                          contents.append(finalLine +"\n"); // will run on UI thread

                           }
                        });

                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                contents.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                          contents.setText(e.getMessage()); // will run on UI thread

                           }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: If the code inside **runOnUiThread()** executes on the main thread, then wouldn't it also block the UI?

Comment: Recently, I discovered that the problem was not with threading. The thread was running well, but whenever the contents of the file were being written into the TextView, the UI was freezing. Small texts didn't cause any problem, but whenever the contents were becoming longer than about 10000 characters, the UI was freezing.

Comment: Damn 10000 chars in `TextView`, certainly not what I was thinking.

Comment: So, do you have any solution for that? How do text file viewers display such long files?

Comment: I am not aware of it, but you can ask this as a new question.

Comment: All right. Since your answer is a partial solution to my question, I am accepting it.